# Hangman Game Not Identifying Correct Letters Guessed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently finished up the basics of Javascript, CSS, HTML, and have started jQuery. I decided that I knew enough to make a simple hangman game, so I've decided to do just that. I have most of it done, however I cannot seem to get the game to replace the dashes at the bottom if they guess the correct letter. Also if they guess the correct letter the game reveals a body part, even though it shouldn't. The code I have to test for the letters is as follows. The entirety of the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcd87/). Since this code does not work the best in jsfiddle, you can download the source [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t42bivgmx1t0vk1/Hangman.rar) (or just copy it from the jsfiddle).

The portion I seem to be having trouble with:

```
function letterCheck(){
    for(var z=0; z < trueWord.length; z++){
        if( trueWord[z] == letter ){
            trueWord[z] = letter;
            numberOfRightLetters++;
            alert("Correct!"); //Test to see if player guessed correct letter
            document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML="<p> Current Word: " + displayedWord + "</p>"; //SUPPOSED to place the letter at the bottom if guessed correctly **not working**
        } else {
            wrongLetter = true; //Tells program that the player guessed the wrong letter
            alert("Incorrect!"); //Test to see if player guessed correct letter
        }
    }

    if(wrongLetter == true){
        numberOfWrongLetters++; //Increases the number of times the player guessed a wrong letter so the program displays the correct body part

        //Displays person and their body parts
        switch(numberOfWrongLetters){
            case(1):
                $('#head').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(2):
                $('#body').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(3):
                $('#LArm').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(4):
                $('#RArm').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(5):
                $('#Lleg').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(6):
                $('#Rleg').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you set `wrongLetter` to `false`. Logically you should initialize the variable to `false` in the `letterCheck` function or set it in the `if` statement where you alert `Correct!`. Also what do you mean to do when you first check if `trueWord[z] == letter` and then if it does you set `trueWord[z] = letter`? Why make that declaration if the condition already exists?

Comment: @Jasper I declared `wrongLetter` to false in the function that detects what letter the player clicked and makes the letter disappear. I see what you mean by doing `trueWord[z] == letter` then `trueWord[z] = letter`, it should be `trueWord[z] == letter` then `displayedWord[z] == letter`.

Comment: Take a look is that the desired behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/Gcd87/1/  ?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Almost. The only problem with this is when I do something such as "jeff/is/cool" and I guess "o" or "f" it only displays one of the letters in the correctly guessed letters box. The man being displayed is working like it should, however.

Comment: Take a look now http://jsfiddle.net/Gcd87/2/

Comment: @EduardoQuintana That works great! What did you end up doing to fix it?

Comment: I put in comments the changes i made i hope it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i made some changes to the function `letterCheck`

```
function letterCheck(letter){

    for(var z=0; z < trueWord.length; z++){
        if( trueWord[z] == letter ){
            numberOfRightLetters++;
            wrongLetter = false;
            //Iterate the true word and when we find letters that match set the letter
            //on the displayed word to the same position it was found on the trueword
            $.each(trueWord,function(l){
                  //l is the index of the letter in the array
                if(trueWord[l] == letter){
                    //replace al the occurrences of the letters on the displayed word
                    displayedWord[l] = letter
                }
            })
            //Removed the alert in each iteration to the if(wrongLetter == true)
            document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML="<p> Current Word: " + displayedWord + "</p>"; //SUPPOSED to place the letter at the bottom if guessed correctly **not working**
            //Added a break to stop the loop on the first ocurrence of the letter
            //this is made to have control on the wrongLetter flag
            break;
        } else {
            wrongLetter = true; //Tells program that the player guessed the wrong letter

        }
    }

    if(wrongLetter == true){
        alert("Incorrect")
        numberOfWrongLetters++; //Increases the number of times the player guessed a wrong letter so the program displays the correct body part

        //Displays person and their body parts
        switch(numberOfWrongLetters){
            case(1):
                $('#head').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(2):
                $('#body').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(3):
                $('#LArm').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(4):
                $('#RArm').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(5):
                $('#Lleg').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
            case(6):
                $('#Rleg').fadeIn("slow");
            break;
        }
    }else{
      alert("Correct!")
      //Added to display one alert correct and not one for each letter
    }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcd87/2/)